# retrieve out parameter from stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created one **stored procedure**  in oracle:

```
PROCEDURE string_opp(input_string IN varchar2,output_string OUT varchar2)
```

Now the problem is how to execute this stored procedure and retrieve the output parameter.i've followed in sql developer:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  outputString VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  EXEC string_opp('input String',:outputString);
END;
```

When i tried this i didn't get anything, could someone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a couple of issues:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
   outputString VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN
  string_opp('input String', outputString);
  dbms_output.put_line(outputString);
END;
```

You can use as the same variable:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
   outputString VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN
  outputString := 'input String';
  string_opp(outputString);
  dbms_output.put_line(outputString);
END;
```

Just define your procedure parameter as IN OUT in place of just OUT.

Check this resource:

http://psoug.org/snippet/FUNCTIONS-IN-OUT-parameter_873.htm

Answer (score 2):

Let say:

If you have Store procedure with output parameter:

```
Create procedure test(name out varchar2(50))
as
begin
name:='testing output parameter';
-- dbms_output.put_line('Output parameter value ' || name );
end;
```

Now execute the above procedure :

```
declare
l_name varchar2(50);
begin
test(l_name);
dbms_output.put_line( 'name = ' || l_ename );
end;
```