# Procedure to check for non duplicate rows in table before insert (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

I wrote a procedure in oracle(using guidance from here) to check for any duplicate values in table so that countries with the same countryId should return some error message as countryId is PK in countries table.Here it is:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_values4 (c_cntry_id IN OUT COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID%TYPE,
                                       c_cntr_name IN COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME%TYPE, 
                                       c_rgn_id IN COUNTRIES.REGION_ID%TYPE)
IS
DECLARE
   outputValue CHAR  := 'JJ';
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO countries(COUNTRY_ID, COUNTRY_NAME,REGION_ID)
    values (user_seq.nextval, c_cntr_name,c_rgn_id);
  c_cntry_id := user_seq.currval;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN dup_val_on_index
  THEN 
    c_cntry_id := null;
END;
/
```

However,when I try to create this procedure,it gives me error PLS-00103.Any idea what could be wrong? (Anything in syntax?).I have been trying since 48 hours but with not much success.Appreciate some help here.

Tx in advance

Comment: What is the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a semi-colon after the list of parameters instead of as. Try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_vals (c_cntry_id OUT COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID%TYPE,
                                       c_cntr_name IN COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME%TYPE, 
                                       c_rgn_id IN COUNTRIES.REGION_ID%TYPE)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO countries(COUNTRY_ID, COUNTRY_NAME,REGION_ID)
    values (user_seq.nextval, c_cntr_name,c_rgn_id)
  Returning country_id into c_cntry_id;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN dup_val_on_index
  THEN 
    c_cntry_id := null;
END;
/
```

Note also that I have used the returning clause to set the value of c_cntry_id.

---

Looking at your edited code, the issue now is that you have got `DECLARE` in your procedure between the `IS` and the `BEGIN`

Also, since you're using a sequence value to insert rows into the table - and, hopefully, this is the only point at which rows could be inserted - that shouldn't ever result in a dup_val_on_index exception.

I've knocked up a test case that will create the dup_val_on_index due to an additional unique constraint on the country_name column, and also shown you two ways of creating the code - as a procedure and as a function, as well as demonstrating how to call them:

```
drop table countries;
drop sequence user_seq;
drop procedure add_country_pr;
drop function add_country_fn;

create table countries (country_id integer primary key,
                        country_name varchar2(50) unique not null,
                        region_id integer);

create sequence user_seq
  start with 1
  maxvalue 99999
  minvalue 1
  nocycle
  cache 20
  noorder;

create or replace procedure add_country_pr (c_cntry_id out countries.country_id%type,
                                            c_cntr_name in countries.country_name%type, 
                                            c_rgn_id in countries.region_id%type)
is
begin
  insert into countries (country_id, country_name,region_id)
  values (user_seq.nextval, c_cntr_name,c_rgn_id)
  returning country_id into c_cntry_id;
exception
  when dup_val_on_index
  then 
    c_cntry_id := null;
end add_country_pr;
/

create or replace function add_country_fn (c_cntr_name in countries.country_name%type, 
                                           c_rgn_id in countries.region_id%type)
return integer
is
  v_cntry_id integer;
begin
  insert into countries (country_id, country_name,region_id)
  values (user_seq.nextval, c_cntr_name,c_rgn_id)
  returning country_id into v_cntry_id;

  return v_cntry_id;
exception
  when dup_val_on_index
  then 
    return null;
end add_country_fn;
/


set serveroutput on;

-- anonymous block used to call the above procedure/function
declare
  v_cntry_id integer;
begin
  add_country_pr (c_cntry_id => v_cntry_id, -- variable to hold the value of the out parameter
                  c_cntr_name => 'GBR', 
                  c_rgn_id => 1);
  commit;

  dbms_output.put_line('add_country_pr 1st call, country_id = "'||v_cntry_id||'"');

  add_country_pr (c_cntry_id => v_cntry_id, -- variable to hold the value of the out parameter
                  c_cntr_name => 'GBR', 
                  c_rgn_id => 1);
  commit;

  dbms_output.put_line('add_country_pr 2nd call, country_id = "'||v_cntry_id||'"');

  v_cntry_id := add_country_fn (c_cntr_name => 'USA', 
                                c_rgn_id => 2);
  commit;

  dbms_output.put_line('add_country_fn 1st call, country_id = "'||v_cntry_id||'"');

  v_cntry_id := add_country_fn (c_cntr_name => 'USA', 
                                c_rgn_id => 2);
  commit;

  dbms_output.put_line('add_country_fn 2nd call, country_id = "'||v_cntry_id||'"');
end;
/

add_country_pr 1st call, country_id = "1"
add_country_pr 2nd call, country_id = ""
add_country_fn 1st call, country_id = "3"
add_country_fn 2nd call, country_id = ""
```

Comment: @user3400060 I've updated my answer to demonstrate how you could write and call your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon after your parameter block, and you are missing your `IS` or `AS` clause:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_vals (c_cntry_id OUT COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID%TYPE,
                                       c_cntr_name IN COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME%TYPE, 
                                       c_rgn_id IN COUNTRIES.REGION_ID%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO countries(COUNTRY_ID, COUNTRY_NAME,REGION_ID)
    values (user_seq.nextval, c_cntr_name,c_rgn_id);
  c_cntry_id := user_seq.currval;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN dup_val_on_index
  THEN 
    c_cntry_id := null;
END;
/
```

Comment: thanks,yes,I was able to create the procedure.However,when I execute it using "execute add_vals('JK','JustK',3)",it throws the errors: "PLS-00363-expression 'JK' cannot be used as an assignment target".Any idea why?

Comment: That would be because your first parameter is defined as an out parameter; you can't assign a value to a text expression!

Comment: thanks,so what would I need to do for having all three parameters accepted?

Comment: You'd need to write an anonymous block, and declare a variable to use as the out parameter. A quick Google shows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649657/retrieve-out-parameter-from-stored-procedure

Comment: ok,can you edit my original code to help me with anonymous block? I am not familiar with "IN" and "OUT" type parameters much.So,I am seeking some guidance.

Comment: Actually,I edited my code to declare my output variable but it is saying "Procedure created with compilation errors"

Comment: Your procedure is written to only accept two parameters (the last two) as inputs. Your first parameter is an output, the numeric sequence. Why would you want to submit 'JK' to your procedure?