# Oracle Stored procedure to insert non-duplicate values and foreign key constraint consideration

Tags: oracle, plsql, foreign-key-relationship, pls-00103

My requirement is to write a procedure to add values in `COUNTRIES` table. But, first it should check if corresponding values exist in another table, `REGIONS` as it is a foreign key. Only if the values exist is the insert into `COUNTRIES` table allowed. Second requirement is that I should not have duplicate values for `country_id` in `COUNTRIES` table as `country_id` is `PK`. I wrote this code, but it is throwing the exception:

```
PLS-00103 Encountered the symbol "WHEN" when expecting one of the following:
begin case
PLS-00103:Encountered the symbol "WHEN" when expecting one of the following: ERROR
```

My code is:

```
create or replace procedure addi5 (c_cntry_id  in out countries.country_id%type,
                                   c_cntr_name in countries.country_name%type, 
                                   c_rgn_id    in countries.region_id%type)
is
    region_exists pls_integer;
begin
    begin
        select 1 into region_exists
        from regions r 
        where r.region_id = c_rgn_id;
    exception
        when no_data_found then
            region_exists := 0;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Region not present '||sqlerrm);
    end;

   BEGIN
     INSERT INTO countries(COUNTRY_ID, COUNTRY_NAME,REGION_ID)
     values (c_cntry_id, c_cntr_name,c_rgn_id);

   EXCEPTION
     WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN 
       c_cntry_id := null;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Already present');
   END;    

   if region_exists = 1 then
     insert into countries(country_id, country_name,region_id)
     values (c_cntry_id, c_cntr_name, c_rgn_id);

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserted');

   ELSE
     WHEN dup_val_on_index
     THEN 
     c_cntry_id := null;

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Already present');
   END IF;

end addi5;
/
```

Can someone please guide me what I am doing wrong? Or how to write or check for these two conditions?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006475/procedure-to-check-for-non-duplicate-rows-in-table-before-insert-oracle

Comment: I would get rid of the primary and foreign keys. Just use inner joins from your source table to regions so you are only loading data that exists in regions. As for the duplicates you can use select minus statements to get rid of those by looking for duplicates based on rowid. This would keep your job from failing and will most likely run a lot faster.

Comment: thanks, can you please edit my code to re-write? I am new to oracle pl/sql

Comment: no i'm not going to do that, you need to beat your head against the wall and figure it out like everyone else

Answer (score 1):

Your coding practice it self is not correct. First you should try to write your logic in sql if possible for readability as well as to reduce context switch between sql and pl/sql engine. Here is the sample code, you might have to add exception handling.

```
create or replace procedure addi5 (c_cntry_id in countries.country_id%type,
                                   c_cntr_name in countries.country_name%type, 
                                   c_rgn_id in countries.region_id%type)
is
begin
  insert into countries select c_cntry_id, c_cntr_name, c_rgn_id from dual
  where c_rgn_id in (select region_id from regions)
  and c_cntry_id not in (select country_id from countries);
  commit;
end;
/
```